# How to minimize the $0$-"norm" with quadratic constraint?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, convex-optimization, least-squares

I have a vector

$$y = Ax + n$$

where vectors $x, y, n$ are $25 \times 1$, matrix $A$ is $25 \times 25$ and near-orthogonal (actually, it's a part of the DFT matrix). Also, $x$ is sparse and has only $5$ non-zero elements.  $A$ and $y$ are known, $n$ is the Gaussian random variable, and I need to recover $x$ as accurately as possible.

How to solve the problem? We don't care about the complexity, the only consideration is the accuracy. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $25 \choose 5$ is rather small, you can enumerate all sparsity patterns and determine which combination gives the highest likelihood for $n$

Comment: @LinAlg I think it’s a good idea but can you kindly tell the specific process as I’m not sure what to do, such as the computing of x after I enumerating it’s non-zero elements’ index.

Comment: What does the title have to do with the actual question?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you know the sparsity pattern of $x$ (enumeration works here), then the problem reduces to $y=Ax+n$ where $x$ is $5 \times 1$, $y$ and $n$ are $25\times 1$ and $A$ is $25\times 5$. My assertion is that the best $x$ is the one for that maximizes the maximum likelihood of $n$:
$$\max_{n,x} \left\{ (2\pi)^{-\frac{k}{2}}(\det\Sigma)^{-\frac{1}{2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(n-\mu\right)\Sigma^{-1}\left(n-\mu\right)} : y = Ax+n \right\},$$
or that minimizes the negative log likelihood:
$$\min_{n,x} \left\{ \frac{k}{2}\log(2\pi) + \frac{1}{2}\log\det\Sigma + \frac{1}{2}\left(y-Ax-\mu\right)\Sigma^{-1}\left(y-Ax-\mu\right) \right\}.$$
Assuming that $n\sim N(0,I)$, this simplifies to:
$$\min_{x} \left\{ ||Ax-y||^2 \right\}.$$
So, just do least squares estimation of the linear model $y=Ax$, and select the sparsity pattern for which $||Ax-y||$ is as small as possible.

Comment: thank you. By the way, if the number of non-zero elemsnts of x is uncertain, for example, can be 5, 6 or 7. Then is there any good idea?

Comment: @LinTIna you have to formulate a criterion to decide between 5, 6 or 7. For example, you can look at the difference in likelihood.

Comment: do you mean I need to enumerate 5,6 and 7. Then look at the result (maybe the norm of y-Ax) to decide it?

Comment: yes, that is one way

Comment: thank you, I got it

Comment: @LinTIna please accept the answer if it solved your problem